# How to fill empty values in a column to the latest record value in KUSTO

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, adx

I have a Date column and value column, I need to create a new column (Expected Date) with Date values w.r.t value column. The screenshot attached here has some sample data. Expected Date column will take the date when there is a value in the value column, it has to take same date value till the next value got updated. I am trying to achieve this with prev(), but its giving result shown (4th column) in the screenshot. I have tried fill_forward() function it didn't work as this is the Date values.
[image]

Comment: could you convert the date into a ticks/unix milliseconds (and later back to datetime) and use fill_forward()?

Comment: tried but didnt work, when i convert it back to datetime values is not converting properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`KQL Query which worked for me:`**

```
let ST = datatable (Date: datetime, Number: int) [
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:00), 2,
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:01), int(null),
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:02), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:03), int(null),
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:04), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:05), 3,
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:06), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:07), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:08), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:09), 4, 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:10), int(null), 
    datetime(2023-01-28 00:00:11), int(null)
]
|extend new_column2=0
| sort by new_column2 asc
|extend rn=row_number();
let x= ST
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
|extend d= iff(Number != int(null),Date,datetime(null))
|summarize c = make_list_with_nulls(d)
| mv-apply with_itemindex=idx ExpDate = c on 
(
    extend fillIndex = iff(isnull(ExpDate), 0, idx)
    | extend fillIndex = row_cumsum(fillIndex, fillIndex != 0)
    | extend ExpDate = c[fillIndex]  
    | summarize ExpDate = make_list_with_nulls(ExpDate)
)
|mv-expand ExpDate
| extend new_column2 = 0
| sort by new_column2 desc
|project-away c
| sort by new_column2 asc
|extend rn=row_number();
let New = 
    ST
    | join kind=inner (x) on rn;
New
|project-away new_column2,new_column21,rn,rn1
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA52STU%20DQBCG7/srxtuS0ASoH7UNNz148aI3Y8gWpnHt7kJgEWr6452ltaVaQxA4kN1n3vl6FVp4eoYYMmHpXSoEficszt0BWqnRh8daL7GcgzTWgxcG9Hxf8iiIppMgnEQzCIJ593k%20RP4QFRJFetzUSnmDdHRCwxA%20HSV%20OU78ipjpoOj1ONGbcfhsHH5LzOUgFgajVMOTFbJXtsXWosnAYJOkuaq1ieKAbaHKSwvLTf8cRJUe%20NLEZd4kpnMZ9xZMkSfbmGxJwb80yarnRU80sxjkasV3zoWLuNeXc7d/aKs789i2qrUWpfxESCmDFmtMlKxs0kj7ljio4hlhoD8moijUBroLaVFLk2Eby6yF%207Zw4hSfQm6A8W6C%204pWUqkHh8KuNFk5Vb6PoVEGNM2s9bqY7bkoN6S01lQpPxz7PYK6DH6E9yp6OYCvAHvq2PQRPNv6d5WMRkATwLYQR/VzW4r%20XFMEGbpFFWX%20jqmdiEZsIP2vTR6xoUxdO2SXXVfvuTSwprXE0hjaPm89t47SLBjhPzL3svm9/9AvDX3hF/LO1tQfBQAA).